# Create C++ Implementation (All functions at once) with Visual Assist X

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-assist-x

I'm using visual studio 2013 Pro Edition with Visual Assist X. Is there away to create all the functions with one command? Right I have to run the create implementation command for each function. Also it seem that visual assist x does not handle the ordering or let you select the ordering of the functions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Create Method Implementations (Shift+Alt+Q) from the name of your class, not its individual methods.

[image: Create Method Implementations]

Comment: Thanks. I cannot believe I missed that.